# Construct parameters in C to call a Ruby C extension with a variable number of args

Tags: c, ruby

I am trying to re-implement this Ruby method:

```
  def reshape new_shape
    t = reshape_clone_structure(new_shape)
    left_params  = [:*]*new_shape.size
    right_params = [:*]*self.shape.size
    t[*left_params] = self[*right_params]
    t
  end
```

As a C extension to a [Ruby matrix library](https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix).

I am stuck on how to pass multiple values to `[]=` which is implemented in an existing C extension with this definition:

```
static VALUE nm_mset(int argc, VALUE* argv, VALUE self)
```

How do I translate the Ruby code `t[*left_params] =` into C?

Comment: Are you familiar with `printf`?

Comment: yes but i dont see how to do it i need t [:*,:*...'size' no of times]

Comment: Could you give a little more context? There is no function definition (either Ruby or C) in the question - it may help a lot to show that. I have written functions which take variable numbers of param in Ruby and as C extensions for gems, and I have never seen the syntax in your question (in fact I have no idea what it does!)

Comment: heres the definition https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/blob/master/lib/nmatrix/nmatrix.rb#L406

Comment: basically the symbols indicate to use full range,the new_shape.size varies,so no. of args vary for diff. cases . i need to do this in c ext.

Comment: @sabby: I don't see how that relates to your question. The method you linked *does not take a variable number of arguments*, but your question is how to pass a variable number of arguments to a Ruby C extension. What, precisely, are you attempting to turn into a C extension (please show the method you want to convert *in the question*, and not just part of it). Also, please explain, by way of C code you have written so far, where you are stuck.

Comment: https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/blob/master/ext/nmatrix/ruby_nmatrix.c#L1909   defines the function for [ ]. I am writing new method which requires the whole range, as implemented in ruby (first link), but i need to write it in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nm_mset` method uses standard conventions for Ruby C extensions. The `argc` variable is a an integer, specifying number of parameters being sent. Then `argv` is a C array/pointer of type `VALUE *` which must contain *all* the *Ruby-ish* parameters (for an assignment, the last of these params is the value of the right hand side). Thirdly `self` is the Ruby Object receiver -  but do remember that this might be either the class or an instance of it depending on how the method has been defined for Ruby.

To call it, you need to construct a `VALUE *` array with each parameter a `VALUE`, sent in the correct order.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
// Assuming you have following values already processed
// Assignments are not shown here - that is work for you!
VALUE self; 
VALUE t; 
int self_size; 
int new_size; 

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Assuming you set above values correctly, the following should
// work.

int i;

// Get reference to :*
VALUE asterisk = ID2SYM( rb_intern("*") );

// NB +1, we need to add call to self[ *right_params ] to end later
VALUE *left_params = ALLOC_N( VALUE, new_size + 1 );
for(i=0;i<new_size;i++) { left_params[i] = asterisk; }

VALUE *right_params = ALLOC_N( VALUE, self_size );
for(i=0;i<self_size;i++) { right_params[i] = asterisk; }

// equivalent to self[ *right_params ], 
// but we push it straight into end of left_params ready for next step
left_params[ new_size ] = nm_mget( self_size, right_params, self );

// equivalent to t[ *left_params ] =
// Note +1 to size again, the last item is the value to assign
nm_mset( new_size + 1, left_params, t );

// Tidy up
xfree( left_params );
xfree( right_params );

return t;
```

Comment: I think i will have to use the libraries alloc , but it works cleanly. I will make sure i am clearer in next questions. The way you explained the workaround is great.

Answer (score 0):

it is doeable in C , first you need to include the header `<stdarg.h>` then set the function to be like this

```
type function(type argument , ...){}
```

after that use the variable type `va_list` and the three functions `va_start` , `va_end` and `va_arg` to "navigate" trought the arguments as shown [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html)